# Django 1.5 - using the new StreamingHttpResponse

Tags: django, django-views

If I implement `StreamingHttpResponse` [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922874/how-to-stream-an-httpresponse-with-django#13429719), the 'streaming' response is not shown until the 10 seconds is up. There isn't much information on [djangoproject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects) except saying it's useful for generating large CSV files while warning that expensive tasks should be performed outside of the request-response cycle.

However, I cannot see that it is working at all using time-intensive code. Is there something about the generator object that prevents this? Here is the code duplicated for reference.

```
import time
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse

def stream_response(request):
    resp = StreamingHttpResponse(stream_response_generator())
    return resp

def stream_response_generator():
    for x in range(1,11):
        yield '{} <br />\n'.format(x)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Your 100 bytes, streaming or not, will absolutely be buffered at the lowest levels of network. Try a million rows for a start.

Comment: @Pavel Thanks for that - I added ' '*1024 to the yield string and it works as desired

Answer (score 2):

[OP's solution converted to answer below]

Pavel's comment pointed out that the problem with my example was with the browser's buffering, which is solved by modifying the amount of data sent, as e.g.

```
yield '{} <br /> {}'.format(x, ' '*1024)
```