# Stream file from remote url to Django view response

Tags: django, response

Is there any way to stream file from remote URL with Django Response (without downloading the file locally)?

```
# view.py
def file_recover(request, *args, **kwargs):    
    file_url = "http://remote-file-storage.com/file/111"

    return StreamFileFromURLResponse(file_url)
```

We have file storage (files can be large - 1 GB and more). We can't share download url (there are security issues). File streaming can significantly 
increase download speed by forwarding download stream to Django response.

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814162/serving-a-downloadable-file-huge-from-remote-with-django) help you at all?

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I was looking for snippets how to implement it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Django has built in [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse) class which should be given an iterator that yields strings as content. In example below I'm using `requests` [Raw Response Content](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content)

```
import requests
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse


def strem_file(request, *args, **kwargs):
    r = requests.get("http://host.com/file.txt", stream=True)

    resp = StreamingHttpResponse(streaming_content=r.raw)

    # In case you want to force file download in a browser 
    # resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="saving-file-name.txt"'

    return resp
```

---

Comment: I found this the only solution in case of serving private S3 image that requires retrieving temporary presigned url. What I don't understand is there's just so little information about this approach online, so I really wonder why this is not mentioned anywhere else when it comes to displaying private s3 image from a frontend webpage (e.g. `<img src="url_to_private_s3_image" />`.