# Stream a file from remote url in django with resume support

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to stream a file from a remote URL directly to user without downloading it in my server.

I tried using the code someone recommended here:

[Stream file from remote url to Django view response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43952946)

But i can't find a way to add resume support.
I tried getting HTTP_RANGE and add a range header to requests.get but it doesn't work.

Is there any way to add resume support or even any other way to serve file from remote URL with resume support?

Comment: for requests, I use  Range and not HTTP_RANGE.  something like: header = {'Range': 'bytes=%d-' % continue_position}

Comment: no i meant getting the HTTP_RANGE from request.META. The range is set correctly like you said but it still doesn't work.