# Simple query causes memory leak in Django

Tags: python, django, memory-leaks

I work in a company that has a large database and I want to perform some update queries on it but it seems to cause a huge memory leak 
the query is as follow

```python
c= CallLog.objects.all()
for i in c:
   i.cdate = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.strptime(i.fixed_date, "%y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
   i.save()
```

I wrote this in the interactive shell of Django

I even tried to use

```
with transaction.atomic()
```

but it didn't work, do you have any idea how can I detect the source of

the dataset I am working on is about 27 million

fixed_date is a calculated property

Comment: Why do you say that it is a memory leak? What is happening when you run this code? Any error stacktrace that you could add?

Comment: i have a 4 gb memory machine and when i run htop , i see all the memory got eaten by Django and the system freeze after that

Comment: You need to use Redis or some kind of Queue handler to process all the data 1 by 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

p = Paginator(CallLog.objects.all().only('cdate'), 2000)
for page in range(1, p.num_pages + 1):
    for i in p.page(page).object_list:
        i.cdate = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.strptime(i.fixed_date, "%y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
        i.save()
```

Slicing a query set does not load all the objects in memory only to get a subset but adds limit and offset to the SQL query before hitting the database.

Comment: i think this piece of code update the whole table with the same value, and i want to update every record with it's calculated fixed_date value.
i thought about F() expression but it doesn't work with calculated properties

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim I edited my answer. Try this, it should work a little better.
If this takes long time and is memory consuming you should think on create an asynchronous task and let the user know when it's done.

Comment: I'll try this one and get back to you

Comment: it works perfectly but so slow , but it doesn't matter as i am doing this one time only

Answer (score 0):

You could try to iterate the queryset in batches; see the [`.iterator()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#iterator) method. See if that improves anything

```
for obj in CallLog.objects.all():
    obj.cdate = pytz.utc.localize(
        datetime.datetime.strptime(obj.fixed_date, "%y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
    obj.save()
```

Here is a related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222176/why-is-iterating-through-a-large-django-queryset-consuming-massive-amounts-of-me) I found, but it is a few years old.

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking it into small blocks (since you have only 4gb of ram)

```
c= CallLog.objects.filter(somefield=somevalue)
```

When its necessary, I usually use a character or number (ID enting in 1,2,3,4 etc)